# can't get the correct plot of fft

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a problem with the plot of the spectrum, I have an audio file on which I run the `fft` function and try to plot its spectrum :

```
    fileName = 'stuff.wav' ;
[y, Fs] = audioread(fileName);
Y = fft(y(:,1));
Y = Y / length(y);
plot(fftshift(abs(Y));
```

and here is what I get : [image: audio spectrum]

the magnitude is correct but the  frequencies aren't.

so I've wrote a small script to test this :

```
fs =8000;
t = 0:1/fs:10;
x = 3*sin(2*pi*5*t);
U = abs(fft(x));
stem(t,fftshift(U));
axis([-20 20 -5 5]);
```

and the result is :

[image: sin]    why the peak is in the right place meaning 5 but I was excpecting a second one in -5 **negative frequencies**why I can see it and how can I scale correctly the X axis ? 
thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ploting the FFT result (`U`) versus *time*, which doesn't make much sense. First generate the frequency axis values, and then use that when plotting `U`:

```
%// Same as in your code:
fs = 8000;
t = 0:1/fs:10;
x = 3*sin(2*pi*5*t);
U = abs(fft(x));

%// Do the following changes to your code:
f = -fs/2:fs/(numel(t)-1):fs/2; %// frequency axis
stem(f, fftshift(U)); %// plot U versus frequency
axis([-10 10 0 15e4]); %// zoom in to see -5 Hz and 5 Hz values
```

[image]

Comment: thanks  for you answer, but when I try it on the audio file the result doesn't make really sense, at least when I compare it to audacity result

Comment: @Engine Well, the approach used for the 5-Hz signal should work for any audio file...